# Understanding dig @ip address

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ip, dig

What is the role of the ip address in the first dig command?

Why are the two results different?

What are the values 11 and 60 showing?

```
dig @1.1.1.1 instagram.com AAAA

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> @1.1.1.1 instagram.com AAAA
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 61356
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1452
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;instagram.com.         IN  AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
instagram.com.      11  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::22e1:be08
instagram.com.      11  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::3d7:facd
instagram.com.      11  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::3e3:495a
instagram.com.      11  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::22c4:a6ae
instagram.com.      11  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::3d1:b623
instagram.com.      11  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::3e6:95e
instagram.com.      11  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::35e:9b98
instagram.com.      11  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::22c0:373d

;; Query time: 135 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Apr 17 00:26:29 GMT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 279
```

```
dig instagram.com AAAA

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> instagram.com AAAA
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 546
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;instagram.com.         IN  AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
instagram.com.      60  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::3405:b701
instagram.com.      60  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::36d1:47be
instagram.com.      60  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::36d2:852d
instagram.com.      60  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::3457:87a8
instagram.com.      60  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::36a5:4ba
instagram.com.      60  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::22c6:3041
instagram.com.      60  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::3e1:6d03
instagram.com.      60  IN  AAAA    2406:da00:ff00::3650:6426

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri Apr 17 00:26:42 GMT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 266
```

Answer (score 1):

`@IPAddress` tells `dig` which DNS server to query. Without it, `dig` queries whatever DNS server your OS is configured to use (probably shown in `/etc/resolv.conf`).

The results could be different because Instagram, or Instagram's CDN, gives out different responses to do load balancing. Or it could be that their CDN is directing you to different CDN edge nodes/servers that are closest to where your DNS query appeared to come from.

`11` and `60` in your examples were the time-to-live values, letting DNS systems know how long they should cache those answers before re-querying for updated answers.